# When I call helper function in Mocha framework, it returns Undefined when called in my test.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have my helper.js file where I defined a function for reading the filenames in a directory:

```
module.exports.getfilenames= function(dirPath)
{
    console.log(dirPath);
    let files= fs.readdir(dirPath, function (err, files) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
      else {
        console.log("\nCurrent directory filenames:");
        files.forEach(file => {
          console.log(file); 
        })
        return files;
      }
    }) 
};

In test.js
I am calling helper function as:
describe('FILES', function()
{
     files=helper.getfilenames(dirPath);//dirPath is a value of path of directory
     it('GET FILES', function(done) {        
     console.log("reading files:"+ files);
     done();
  })
})
```

Output:

```
reading files: Undefined
```

Please suggest how to resolve the files object in test.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.readdir` is an async function, you need to use the sync version [`readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options):

```
let files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);
files.forEach(file => {
  console.log(file); 
})
return files;
```

Otherwise you can use the async version but some code changes are required.

Comment: sync call to readdir method solved the problem. Thanks